# Set last taken image automatically form gallery in image view

Tags: android, android-camera

[please check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlM2D.jpg)I need to set last taken image  form gallery in image view or on Image button automatically just like used in default camera ,some body help me to sort out this problem

Answer (score 0):

We can get the last taken image from MediaStore,

```
String[] proj = new String[]{
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
    };

final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
        .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, 
               null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String lastImageLocation = cursor.getString(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your answer cannot solve my problem. i want to show gallery in button like in default camera when you capture image that shows on button .look my updated answer ,see image